# SQL Query to count rows from table A which fall between two dates which come from two rows of table B

Tags: sql, count, range, match

Table B has a date column, using the date from the first row as 'date start' and the date from the second row as 'data end', count how many rows of Table A have a data column whose value falls between 'date start' and 'date end'. Then move onto the second and third row etc.

Table A

| date |
| --- |
| 10:00 |
| 10:01 |
| 10:05 |
| 10:20 |
| 10:21 |
| 10:22 |
| 10:23 |
| 10:24 |

Table B

| dateB |
| --- |
| 10:00 |
| 10:10 |
| 10:20 |
| 10:30 |

Result

| date | Qty |
| --- | --- |
| 10:00 | 3 |
| 10:10 | 0 |
| 10:20 | 5 |
| 10:30 | 0 |

Comment: Please TAG your specific RDBMS

Comment: `10:00` etc is not a date. Should this be called *Time*?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using that B table you can use this(according to the your logic):

```
create table test1(entry time);

insert into test1(entry) values
('10:00'),
('10:01'),
('10:05'),
('10:20'),
('10:21'),
('10:22'),
('10:23'),
('10:24')
;

create table test2 (entry_int time,
out_int time);

insert into test2 values
('10:00', '10:10'),
('10:20', '10:30')
;
```

Then you can use:

```
SELECT entry_int "entry",
       out_int   "out",
       Count(*)
FROM   test1 t1
       JOIN test2 t2
         ON t1.entry >= t2.entry_int
            AND t1.entry <= t2.out_int
GROUP  BY entry_int,
          out_int;
```

Also, if you want to stick with your table B then you can use this one:

```
create table test3 (entry time);

insert into test3 values
('10:00'),
('10:10'),
('10:20'),
('10:30'),
('10:40'),
('10:50')
;

WITH interval_tab
     AS (SELECT *,
                Row_number()
                  OVER (
                    ORDER BY entry ) row_num
         FROM   test3),
     mode_tab
     AS (SELECT entry,
                CASE
                  WHEN Mod (row_num, 2) = 1 THEN 'entry'
                  ELSE 'out'
                END mode
         FROM   interval_tab),
     last_tab
     AS (SELECT entry,
                Lead(entry)
                  OVER (
                    ORDER BY entry) "out",
                mode
         FROM   mode_tab),
     tab_test2
     AS (SELECT t.entry,
                t.out
         FROM   last_tab t
         WHERE  mode = 'entry')
SELECT t2.entry "entry",
       t2.out   "out",
       Count(*)
FROM   test1 t1
       JOIN tab_test2 t2
         ON t1.entry >= t2.entry
            AND t1.entry <= t2.out
GROUP  BY t2.entry,
          t2.out;
```

[DB Fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=19c09b8e25eb685694feb34d1d3ddcef)